# What is the bicycle Danny MacAskill uses in his "Way Back Home" video?

Tags: bmx

I was wondering whether someone could help me identify what is the bicycle Danny MacAskill uses in his [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj6ho1-G6tw&t=25). If it is unable to determine exactly what model he has, could you guys please tell me a rough estimate how much a bicycle that can handle such jumps would cost? What brand would you recommend?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - I have enjoyed a few of Danny MacAskill's videos since. There is an art to what he does and he demonstrates how much of the impossible can be done, making it look so easy. Good luck in taking up the sport!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He rides a prototype trials bike by Inspired Bicycles that will be called 'Skye' when it comes out.

Full details on his rig:

http://www.inspiredbicycles.com/danny_macaskill_r3.php

Inspired sell frames that you can build up to your own specification, useful if you already have a bike that isn't quite up to the job as you can move the parts across and go from there. They also sell complete bikes.

I am sure someone can correct me on this, however, the mainstream brands do not really create anything that comes near to what you get with an Inspired trials bike. There are other brands, e.g. Mission, you may want to see what your nearest LBS has, chances are that they may have someone working there that knows their stuff and has passion for it.

For now it would not do any harm to email Inspired Bicycles to see when the 'Skye' frame/bike is out and find out how much it is likely to cost.

Answer (score 2):

I found some pictures if the bike at euro bike 2011. It has some changes since "way back home" like two disk brakes. I look forward to buying one next year when inspired said it would be out.

Link for photos
http://singletrackworld.com/2011/09/eurobike-2011-danny-macaskills-inspired-trials-bike/

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a similar bicycle style that's affordable, I'd recommend the Echo Trials bikes. They make 20", 24" and 26" versions, and are sold for less than $1000 with hydraulic disc front brakes and hydraulic rim rear brakes (the same setup that Danny has). Here's a [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/product-fm/422624924-ECHO-24-Trials-Bike-in-stock-wholesalers.html) and a picture:

[image: Echo 24 Trials Bicycle]

They aren't exactly what he's riding, but they are at least somewhat comparable in components and setup, and these are affordable.